# MySQL INSERT with two different UNIQUE constraints

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a table created with:

```
CREATE TABLE userSessions (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userId VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  startTime TIMESTAMP NULL,
  endTime TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX(startTime),
  INDEX(endTime),
  UNIQUE(userId, startTime),
  UNIQUE(userId, endTime)
);
```

And I want to know, if inserting a row that has a duplicate key, on which constraint it was duplicate, on the startTime or on the endTime. 
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE userSessions (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userId VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  startTime TIMESTAMP NULL,
  endTime TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX(startTime),
  INDEX(endTime),
  UNIQUE idxStartTime(userId, startTime),
  UNIQUE idxEndTime(userId, endTime)
);
```

When an insert fails now the error will clearly state which constraint was violated:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'value' for key 'idxStartTime'
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that (as far as I know) there's no other way to get the key name except parsing the error message (and the format might change slightly depending on the server version).

Comment: In all honesty a programmer should never have a need to know this anyway - duplicating timestamps should never be possible, and even if so the business logic should check validity before attempting the `INSERT`-query.

Comment: Enforcing that from the client probably involves locking the complete table. Depending on the scenario it might be overkill. Having an API to get the key name has its usages.

Comment: @Niels, How can I check validity? By SELECTing? isn't it less efficient to test validity on every INSERT?

Comment: Yes, that's less efficient, but coding without errorchecking "and just seeing whether it works" it considered rather bad practice. Unless you're doing thousands of inserts every minute I wouldn't bother with the performance and just do a proper checkup if you want to give a proper error.